# Как посчитать количество сравнений и копирований для сортировки слиянием?

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, сортировка-слиянием

Хотел бы узнать, как можно теоретически посчитать количество обменов и копирований для сортировки слиянием в лучшем, среднем и худшем случае. Для этого есть какая-то формула, или ее нужно выводить. Если нужно выводить, то как это сделать?
Спасибо.

Comment: А смысл в таком значении? O(N log N), по-моему, вполне информативно, нет?

Answer (score 0):

Для классической сортировки слиянием нет худшего и лучшего случая, т.к. на каждом этапе нужно сделать n или 2n (в зависимости от выбранного использования массивов) копирований, а таких этапов log n